# spaces are deleted in create_at model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have some weird issue. I render in my view some

```
render json: some_data
```

this `some_data` is a collection of object attributes. The problem is that when I get the response back in my javascript, the rails provided `created_at` has no space in it (`2014-04-04T13:51:24.660Z`). Why and how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`created_at` in rails is timestamp obejcts, not a string and cannot have 'spaces'. What you see in the console is it's string representation returned by calling inspect on this object.

`to_json` method on DateTime is defined to return `strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")` or `strftime('"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %z"')` depending on value of `ActiveSupport.use_standard_json_time_format`. If you want any other format to be sent, you need to modify your `some_data` so that created_at is a string with requested format. There is always an option to override `to_json` method on DateTime, but I wouldn't recommend it
.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) so doesn't need fixing